# Java installation problem

Tags: 12.04, java

I cannot install java on my ubuntu 12.04:

```
    zero@ghostrider:~$ sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
[sudo] password for zero: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-demo' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jre-headless' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'uwsgi-plugin-jwsgi-openjdk-6' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-jre' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-source' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-dbg' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk7-jdk' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-doc' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jre-zero' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-demo' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-jre-headless' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-jdk' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-jre' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-jre-lib' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-jre-zero' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-dbg' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-doc' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jdk' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jre' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-source' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jre-lib' for regex 'openjdk*'
Note, selecting 'uwsgi-plugin-jvm-openjdk-6' for regex 'openjdk*'
Package uwsgi-plugin-jvm-openjdk-6 is not installed, so not removed
Package uwsgi-plugin-jwsgi-openjdk-6 is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-6-dbg is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-6-demo is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-6-doc is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-6-jdk is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-6-jre is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-6-jre-headless is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-6-jre-lib is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-6-source is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-6-jre-zero is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-7-dbg is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-7-demo is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-7-doc is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-7-jdk is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-7-jre is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-7-jre-headless is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-7-jre-lib is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-7-jre-zero is not installed, so not removed
Package openjdk-7-source is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u3-0~eugenesan~precise4) ...
Downloading...
--2012-06-11 23:56:42--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-    7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 64.209.77.18
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|64.209.77.18|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz [following]
--2012-06-11 23:56:42--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 95.101.122.174
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|95.101.122.174|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]
--2012-06-11 23:56:44--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|64.209.77.18|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: `./jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz'

 0K .....                                                 100% 1007K=0.005s

2012-06-11 23:56:44 (1007 KB/s) - `./jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz' saved [5307/5307]

Download done.
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Errors were encountered         while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
zero@ghostrider:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/java
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~eugenesan/+archive/java
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-        keyring /tmp/tmp.uGcZHfsoNF --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring         /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver     hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv 4346FBB158F4022C896164EEE61380B28313A596
gpg: requesting key 8313A596 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 8313A596: "Launchpad synergy+" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
zero@ghostrider:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                     
Ign http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease                   
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                   
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                 
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                       
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                      
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                     
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                          
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                    
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                      
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                    
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                    
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages              
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg          
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages    
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex           
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex             
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources                  
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources            
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources              
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources            
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                        
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages      
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages      
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources                
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources          
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources            
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources          
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages          
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages    
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages      
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages    
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources         
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex 
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex   
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                   
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en             
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en     
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en           
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en       
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en         
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en   
Hit http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
zero@ghostrider:~$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java7-installer is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u3-0~eugenesan~precise4) ...
Downloading...
--2012-06-11 23:57:11--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-    7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 64.209.77.18
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|64.209.77.18|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz [following]
--2012-06-11 23:57:11--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 95.101.122.174
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|95.101.122.174|:443...     connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]
--2012-06-11 23:57:12--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|64.209.77.18|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: `./jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz'

 0K .....                                                 100%  976K=0.005s

2012-06-11 23:57:12 (976 KB/s) - `./jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz' saved [5307/5307]

Download done.
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Errors were encountered     while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
zero@ghostrider:~$
```

Comment: `sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz` means that there were a problem with the file, either the checksum or the downloaded file are corrupted. For your information, I'm running OpenJDK6 with no problem, in two machines with 12.04.

Comment: It does not seem possible to me that the downloaded file is corrupted. I tried it from three different mirrors too; but nothing changed.

Comment: Note that the file retrieved was "http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html" and so technically, it *was* a corrupted download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution that I found:

First, uninstall existing one:

```
sudo apt-get remove oracle-java7-installer
```

Then:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java 
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Hope it works for you too.

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial on how to [install Oracle's Java](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/). 
Don't forget to change the version's name to the one you're going to install.